# URL keep appending in spring mvc application

Tags: spring, url, model-view-controller, mapping

i am new to spring and i have developed an application using spring mvc. i have created controllers which use request mapping annotations to handle mapping between jsp to controller (for example; a controller named Driver have several mappings like /drivers/update/{id}, /drivers/edit/{id} etc.). but when i use /drivers/update/{id} mapping and i want to use /drivers/edit/{id} mapping at very next call, the URL changes to "***myproject/drivers/update/any_id/drivers/edit/any_id***" in the URL of browser.

```
       I think it's spring mapping handler concept related problem, but i don't know what it is actually. Please don't ask the code to be uploaded because i don't have code now. Please help(i am sure someone have already faced the problem)
```

Comment: check if there is a slash before the mapping path which is given in JSP. If not add one.

Comment: look again my question and please elaborate

Comment: please post the jsp contains these mappings, also how you are trying to call the edit method?

Comment: one jsp uses drivers/update/{id} and one uses drivers/edit/{id}. if we are using first and want to go for second, it will get appended in url of browser like this /drivers/update/id/drivers/edit/id

Answer (score 0):

I guess the URI pattern you are using is not correctly written. Prepend a forward slash `/` in the URI pattern.

For example:

- `@requestMapping("/yoururl")` - correct.
- `@requestMapping("yoururl")` - incorrect.

Note: without `/` it will keep appending the URL. I tried this way and it was solved in my case.